# Vue/webpack/Laravel Mix - TypeError: o is not a function only in production mode

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack, vuejs2

Good morning.

I use Vue 2 with Laravel Mix/Webpack and node version 14.18.1. When I run npm run dev everything is working. But when I run npm run production then I get the error: TypeError: o is not a function. Does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/az7hk.jpg

My webpack.mix.config:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.webpackConfig({
    output: {
        publicPath: '/laravel/',
        chunkFilename: 'js/chunks/[name].js?id=[chunkhash]'
    }
});

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/laravel/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/laravel/css')
    .sourceMaps()
    .setPublicPath('public/laravel/')
    .setResourceRoot('../')
    .version();
```

My package.json:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18.1",
        "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
        "core-js": "^3.2.1",
        "cross-env": "^5.2.1",
        "jquery": "^3.6.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
        "vue": "^2.6.10",
        "vue-server-renderer": "^2.6.10",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.25",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.11.2",
        "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^0.1.7",
        "@google/markerclustererplus": "^2.1.11",
        "bootstrap-vue": "^2.17.3",
        "google-maps-api-loader": "^1.1.1",
        "icheck": "^1.0.2",
        "intl-tel-input": "^15.1.2",
        "magnific-popup": "^1.1.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
        "nouislider": "^13.1.5",
        "pretty-checkbox-vue": "^1.1.9",
        "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.3",
        "sweetalert2": "^7.33.1",
        "v-lazy-image": "^1.3.2",
        "v-mask": "^2.2.3",
        "vue-clickaway": "^2.2.2",
        "vue-cookie-law": "^1.8.0",
        "vue-flickity": "^1.2.1",
        "vue-float-label": "^1.6.1",
        "vue-gallery": "^1.5.0",
        "vue-loading-skeleton": "^1.1.9",
        "vue-notification": "^1.3.20",
        "vue-perfect-scrollbar": "^0.1.0",
        "vue-slider-component": "^2.8.16",
        "vue-tel-input": "^2.5.0",
        "vuex": "^3.1.1",
        "vuse": "^0.1.1",
        "webpack-jquery-ui": "^2.0.1",
        "wnumb": "^1.1.0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try a clean install of packages?

1. delete `node_modules`
2. `npm cache clean`
3. `npm install`

If this doesn't work, I suggest you check your webpack config for production for the `vue` compiler it uses.

Also try to install `vue` and `vue-template-compiler` in the same version.

Comment: Yes, I deleted node_modules, run npm cache clearn and npm install but it doesn't work.
In webpack.mis.js I habe the following config:



mix.webpackConfig({
    output: {
        publicPath: '/laravel/',
        chunkFilename: 'js/chunks/[name].js?id=[chunkhash]'
    }
});

Comment: Please share all the webpack config in your question so that we can help!

Comment: I added the files in the question

Comment: Added more in my answer, hope this helps.

Comment: I changed the version of vue-template-compiler to the same version of vue and reinstall npm. Its working! Thanks!