# Vue v2 / webpack / laravel mix : TypeError: i is not a function only once I've run production

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, vue-component, laravel-mix

[Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAaha.png)

Hello! I'm working on a project previously created by an ex coworker in Vue and laravel-mix. The project works locally after npm run development, but when I run npm run production, it provides the above error. The error is a part of the home.js file compiled after production. This is only in the console, the build is successful in the terminal.

I haven't worked with any of these before, so any help would be much appreciated.

My package.json:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "browser-sync": "^2.23.7",
        "cross-env": "^5.2.1",
        "sass-resources-loader": "^2.2.5"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
        "vue": "^2.5.13",
        "vue-resource": "^1.5.0"
    }
}
```

my webpack.mix.js:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix').setPublicPath('public');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix
    .js('resources/js/home.js', 'assets/js')
    .js('resources/js/our-people.js', 'assets/js')
    .js('resources/js/our-clients.js', 'assets/js')
    .sass('resources/scss/style.scss', 'assets/css')
    .options({
        processCssUrls: false
    });

mix.browserSync({
    proxy: false,
    watch: true,
    server: {
        baseDir: "public",
        // directory: true
    }
});

mix.version();
```

my webpack.config.js:

```
/**
 * As our first step, we'll pull in the user's webpack.mix.js
 * file. Based on what the user requests in that file,
 * a generic config object will be constructed for us.
 */
let mix = require('../src/index');

let ComponentFactory = require('../src/components/ComponentFactory');

new ComponentFactory().installAll();

require(Mix.paths.mix());

/**
 * Just in case the user needs to hook into this point
 * in the build process, we'll make an announcement.
 */

Mix.dispatch('init', Mix);

/**
 * Now that we know which build tasks are required by the
 * user, we can dynamically create a configuration object
 * for Webpack. And that's all there is to it. Simple!
 */

let WebpackConfig = require('../src/builder/WebpackConfig');

module.exports = new WebpackConfig().build();
```

my home.js :

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueResource from 'vue-resource';

Vue.use(VueResource);

// import base components
import navComponent from './components/NavComponent.vue';
import headerComponent from './components/HeaderComponent.vue';
import footerComponent from './components/FooterComponent.vue';

// spin up Vue instances
new Vue({
    el: 'nav',
    render: h => h(navComponent)
});

new Vue({
    el: 'header',
    render: h => h(headerComponent)
});


new Vue({
    el: 'footer',
    render: h => h(footerComponent)
});
```

thank you so much!

I tried this: [Vue/webpack/Laravel Mix - TypeError: o is not a function only in production mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76108557/vue-webpack-laravel-mix-typeerror-o-is-not-a-function-only-in-production-mode) (no change)

I have checked the logic is working on the Vue components, and I've checked that the mix-manifest is in the right part of the directory.

Comment: update: didn't find a solution. Ended up uploading the dev build. There was an issue with the minification and the <script> conditional logic in my components, as my header and nav were the problem while my footer without any other logic than rendering worked.